# class destructor in specific case

Tags: c++, class

Does class below need destructor ~MyString(){delete ptr}

```
class MyString
{
  char* ptr;
  int size;
 public:
  ~MyString() { delete ptr};
   MyString(char* str) : ptr(str),size(strlen(ptr)){}; 
};
```

if I initialize it this way

```
int main()
{
 MyString s1("ddddd");  // no new --> no delete ?
}
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No! No `delete` is needed here. Never, because the constructor got the pointer from someone else. The one who passed the pointer should take care of what happens with it concerning the cleanup. In fact, your class is even broken, I think. I'm not sure (as I'm not a C++ expert) but you would have to take a copy of the `char*`.

And FYI: did you know `std::string` exists?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using c++11, this shared pointer will take care of the pointer deletion. smart_pointer and auto_pointer can be the options, if you are working with the previous versions of the c++.

```
#include <memory>

class MyString
{
  shared_ptr<char> ptr;
  int size;
public:
 ~MyString() {};
 MyString(shared_ptr<char> str) : ptr(str),size(strlen(ptr.get())){}; 
};
```